# How to deploy app to 0.0.0.0 and port 5000 on Railway.app?

Tags: python, deployment, dockerfile

I am trying to deploy my Flask app on railway.app. I have made a Flask backend and a React Frontend, and am using a Dockerfile to build my App.
The Console is giving me this warning -

`Looks like your app is listening on 127.0.0.1. You may need to listen on 0.0.0.0 instead.`

**Dockerfile**

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.7-slim

WORKDIR /bank-loan-status

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000/tcp
EXPOSE 5000/udp

CMD [ "python", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

**Python script**

```
import pickle
from flask import Flask,request,app,jsonify,render_template, send_from_directory
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

app= Flask(__name__,static_url_path='', static_folder='FRONTEND/build')
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
# Load the model
xgb_model = pickle.load(open('xgbclassifier.pkl','rb'))
scalar = pickle.load(open('scaling.pkl', 'rb'))

@app.route('/')
@cross_origin()
def template():
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder,'index.html')

@app.route('/predict_api', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def predict_api():
    data = request.json['data']
    print(np.array(list(data.values())).reshape(1,-1))
    new_data = scalar.transform(np.array(list(data.values())).reshape(1,-1))
    op = xgb_model.predict(new_data)
    print(op[0])
    return  jsonify(int(op[0]))

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def predict():
    data=[float(x) for x in request.form.values()]
    f_ip = scalar.transform(np.array(data).reshape(1,-1))
    print(f_ip)
    output = xgb_model.predict(f_ip)[0]
    return render_template(app.static_folder, "index.html", prediction_text="The predicted loan status is {}".format(output))

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port=5000)
```

I tried to change the executing command in Dockerfile but still could not fix this warning.

command -

`CMD [ "python", "-m", "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=5000"]`

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you should create environment varriable on railway.app, it overwrite default port of railway server

> PORT=5000

also you can check docs https://docs.railway.app/deploy/exposing-your-app

Comment: An interesting idea "railway team," but what should you do if you need to open multiple ports?